# I can't make SplashScreen work on an Android phonegap project

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I installed the plugin using CLI thru this: `$ cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-splashscreen.git`

My cordova version is: `3.4.0-0.19.17` 
cordova.js version of my project is: `3.4.0`

I followed the instruction in their documentation but I can't seem to make it work. Here is my **res** directory:

[image]

Here is my config.xml files regarding splashscreen:

**config.xml**

```
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="www/res/drawable/splashscreen.png" />
</platform>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
```

my device ready function on index.html:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.show();
    redirectTo("./main.html");
}
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
   follow the instructions on the PhoneGap documentation page:                                        
   http://docs.phonegap/en/3.4.0/config_ref_images.md.html#Icons%20and%20Splash%20Screens


   The size for each should be:

   xlarge (xhdpi): at least 960 × 720
   large (hdpi): at least 640 × 480
   medium (mdpi): at least 470 × 320
   small (ldpi): at least 426 × 320
   Make sure you have these in config.xml:

  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />

  then put copies of your splash screen image (each having the correct 
  resolution for the target platform) in the drawable* folders, like this:

   platforms/android/res/drawable/screen.png
   platforms/android/res/drawable-hdpi/screen.png
   platforms/android/res/drawable-ldpi/screen.png
   platforms/android/res/drawable-mdpi/screen.png
   platforms/android/res/drawable-xhdpi/screen.png

   Also, suggest removing this from your config file:

   <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
```

Comment: what should be the size of  platforms/android/res/drawable/screen.png ?

Comment: The size for each should be:

   xlarge (xhdpi): at least 960 × 720
   large (hdpi): at least 640 × 480
   medium (mdpi): at least 470 × 320
   small (ldpi): at least 426 × 320

Comment: yes thank you i can see that on your answer, but what I'm asking is for the default screen.png? not hdli/ldpi/mdpi/xhdpi

Comment: drawable/screen.png is defaul folder. if are u not using any folders.  Here you can you any image and xml files.